# Denying permissions inside Settings

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm developing an Android application, and for requiring permissions I'm using the [Easy Permissions library](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions). Everything works fine until the user denies any of the permissions inside Settings.

[image]

- Then, this dialog is always shown, consecutively, until the user accepts the permission.
- If the user press "Don't ask again", the smartphone becames unstable, restarting the application, but not showing the dialog.
- If the user closes the application, it starts again and again, until the user goes to Settings and accept the permission that was denied.

I'm testing the application using a Samsung Galaxy S6, with Android Nougat (7.0), and I don't know if this is a system problem, or if I did something wrong inside my code.

This is my MainActivity class where the EasyPermission library is implemented:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
    EasyPermissions.RationaleCallbacks, 
    EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks{

    private static String[] PERMS = 
        {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, PERMS)){
            create();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMS, 0);              
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, 
        @NonNull String[] permissions, 
        @NonNull int[] grantResults){
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, 
                permissions, 
                grantResults);

            EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, 
                    permissions, 
                    grantResults, 
                    this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, 
        @NonNull List<String> perms) {
        if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getApplication(), PERMS)) {
            create();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, 
        @NonNull List<String> perms) {
            finishAffinity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRationaleAccepted(int requestCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRationaleDenied(int requestCode) {

    }

    public void create() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `onRequestPermissionsResult` , you have called for EasyPermissions again which makes a loop. Change your `onRequestPermissionsResult` to this :

```
int permissionCheck = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    for (int permission : grantResults) {
      permissionCheck = permissionCheck + permission;
    }
    if ((grantResults.length > 0) && permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  create()
}
```

Comment: I've tried, but as it's documented [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions#usage), it only forward the results to EasyPermissions. And I've tried to take it, and the problem still remains.

Comment: Instead of  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMS, 0);   in onCreate use this : EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
        new PermissionRequest.Builder(this, RC_CAMERA_AND_LOCATION, perms)
                .setRationale(R.string.camera_and_location_rationale)
                .setPositiveButtonText(R.string.rationale_ask_ok)
                .setNegativeButtonText(R.string.rationale_ask_cancel)
                .setTheme(R.style.my_fancy_style)
                .build());   

Just change RC_CAMERA_AND_LOCATION according to your permissions

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort trying to help me, but as I've stated it has nothing to do with EasyPermissions. I'm using a framework, that in the background, forces the user to accept the permissions, and if he declines it becomes unstable. I've already talked to them and they will try to solve this issue.

Comment: Awesome ! Do share the solution once fixed .